# Angular js dynamic scope variables

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have to show error for each row in a List.

HTML code

```
   <tr ng-repeat="model in models">
     <td>
      <div role="alert">
       <span class="error" ng-show="errorField_{{models.indexOf(model)}}" translate="eror"></span>
      </div>
     </td>
   </tr>
```

`ng-show` errorField_1, errorField_2..... and so on...

Now how i can i get hold of ng-show variable in controller class ? Any clue for example if i want to change particular variable state. I dont know how to get hold of the dynamicity.

```
$scope.errorField_12 = false;
```

Comment: try ng-show=" 'errorField_' +{{models.indexOf(model)}} "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of declare seprate variable in scope.

Try to use property in models

Like this

```
   <tr ng-repeat="model in models">
     <td>
      <div role="alert">
       <span class="error" ng-show="model.isError" translate="eror"></span>
      </div>
     </td>
   </tr>
```

Make `isError` true or false to show/hide

Like you wanna to show first item's error

```
$scope.models[0].isError = true;
```